# Derivation of a commutator in the Luttinger liquid theory

Tags: condensed-matter, strong-correlated

I am reading the book by Nagaosa: [quantum field theory in strongly correlated electronic systems](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540659815). In chapter 2, he introduces the Luttinger liquid theory. 
I find some difficulty to reproduce his equation 2.1.26 on page 28.

Basically the problem is like this.

We have

$$ [\rho_R(x), \rho_R(x')] = -\frac{i}{2\pi } \partial_x \delta(x- x' ) $$

and

$$  \rho_R (x) = \partial_x \phi_R(x) /2 \pi , $$

then it is claimed that

$$  [\phi_R(x), \phi_R(x' )] = i \pi  \text{sgn} (x-x' ).   $$

I tried to derive this equation as follows:

$$ [\phi_R(x), \phi_R(x' )] =  (2\pi)^2 \int_{-\infty}^x d s_1 \int_{-\infty}^{x'} d s_2  [\rho_R(s_1), \rho_R(s_2)]  \\
= (2\pi)^2 \int_{-\infty}^x d s_1 \int_{-\infty}^{x'} d s_2 \left( -\frac{i}{2\pi } \right) \partial_{s_1} \delta(s_1- s_2 )  \\ 
= - i 2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{x'} d s_2  \delta(x- s_2 )  \\
= - i 2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{x'} d s_2  \delta(s_2 -x ) = -i2\pi \theta(x'- x) . $$

Where is it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Following the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) on the sign function, $d\mathrm{sgn}(x)/dx=2\delta(x)$.  So you could use that to replace the last line of your derivation.  You could also switch the order of the arguments at the end to eliminate the minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a bit confused about this derivation.

First, I do not really agree with Van Dyke's answer, rigorously speaking, the Sgn function does not have a derivative at x=0, and even you use that in the last step, what you'll get should be:

$-i\pi\ \lbrace sgn(x'-x)-sgn(-\infty-x)\rbrace$

which is still not the answer given in the book.

As for the derivation in the question, I think from the $\textbf{second}$ line to the $\textbf{third}$ line, you should have

$-i2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{x'}ds_2 \lbrace \delta (x-s_2)-\delta(-\infty -s2) \rbrace$

but even we have this, we could only get the correct answer by $\textit{assuming}$ $\int_{ -\infty }^{x'}ds_2 \delta(-\infty -s2)=\frac{1}{2} $ ( not suer if this is true... ). To be honest, I'm really confused about the fact that this apprasch does not give us the correct answer, of course, the approach used in Nagaosa's book is correct.

I hope someone who has a better understanding about this problem can post the answer here.